# Seed User with custom role in EF6 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having trouble figuring out how to seed additional users and roles into my MVC5 application, using EF6 code first. In order to debug the `Seed` method from the `Configure.cs` since `update-database` was not working, I wrote this controller,

```
public ActionResult test() {

        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "basic" });

        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var adminthere = context.Users.Any(n => n.UserName == "Admin");
        var basicthere = context.Users.Any(n => n.UserName == "Basic");

        // Create Dummy basic account
        if (!basicthere) {

            var basicUser = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "Basic" };
            userManager.Create(basicUser, "test");
            var _id = basicUser.Id;
            userManager.AddToRole(basicUser.Id, "basic");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The debugger throws an exception at the `userManager.AddToRole(basicUser.Id, "basic");` call saying "UserID not found"? Here is a screenshot including variable values from the debug session:

[image]
What is the problem? Also, the *exact same code* (changing the words "basic" for "Admin") works for seeding the database with the `Admin` user in role "admin". Why?

EDIT EDIT: moved edit I posted here previoulsy to a real answer below.

Comment: no idea? Maybe you could just add your edit as an answer? +1 to balance out as the question seems legitimate.

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvote either, but yes, please post your edit as an answer. As it stands, no one else can really answer because you've solved the problem, but without an actual answer, this question will remain in the unanswered list indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggested I will post my this as an answer:

The line of code `userManager.Create(basicUser, "test");` didn't succeed - the passwort must at least have 6 characters. So while creating the basicUser `ApplicationUser` instance worked (and hence the `_id` was not `null`) I didn't have an `IdentityUser` of that `_id`. On admin it succeeded previously bc. I had a different pwd that I didn't want to post here ...